# How can I mock or stub QUdpSocket in my program

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt5, googletest, googlemock

I have a simple init method in the ServerUDP class. Its purpose is to initialize the soket to work
I would like to test the class using gmock

The method declaration in the QAbstractSocket class that allows the sokent to be set to an address looks like this

```cpp
bool bind(const QHostAddress &address, quint16 port = 0, BindMode mode = DefaultForPlatform);
```

I make the mock class and objects as follows

```cpp
class QUdpSocketMock : public QUdpSocket
{
public:
//    MOCK_METHOD(bool, bind, (const QHostAddress&, quint16, BindMode));
    MOCK_METHOD3(bind, bool(const QHostAddress&, quint16, BindMode));
};

class ServerUDPTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    QUdpSocketMock socketMock;
    ServerUDP serverUDP{socketMock};
};
```

My test case works so that the bind method returns a default value and EXPECT_CALL screams that the bind method was never called

```
TEST_F(ServerUDPTest, TestCase)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(socketMock, bind).WillOnce(Return(false));
    EXPECT_EQ(Error_Code_T::ERROR, serverUDP.init());
}
```

How can I test my class without using real components from qt. Maybe the problem is that the QUdpSocket class is a QObject and that has some effect on it?

UdpSocket class definition:

```cpp
class ServerUDP : public QObject, public ServerInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ServerUDP(QUdpSocket& socket_, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~ServerUDP() {};

    virtual Error_Code_T init();

    virtual Error_Code_T start();

    virtual Error_Code_T stop();

    virtual Error_Code_T deinit();

public slots:
    virtual void readData();

private:
    QUdpSocket& socket;

    QString hostName;
    QString localHostAddress;
    quint16 port;

    ServerUDP() = delete;
    ServerUDP(ServerUDP&) = delete;
    ServerUDP& operator=(ServerUDP&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: What is `serverUDP`? How does it get its `QUdpSocket`?

Comment: serverUDP is my class using QUdpSocket. Implementation of the class is not important. udpsocket is passed as a reference to the class

Comment: Okay, so it's not slicing. What about `EXPECT_CALL`? You missed the `()` and matchers in your example, and since `bind()` is overloaded, it could matter.